# Git pull remote from different branch other than master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I wanted to pull code from a different branch other than master i.e there are two branch master and dummy, the master branch is some commit ahead of dummy branch and dummy contain some commits that are not in the master branch so how do I pull these both branch locally as with there different commits.

I have tried first creating dummy branch and pull that from remote but then it contain commits from master branch

`git clone repolink`

`git checkout -b dummy`

`git pull upstream dummy`

I know about cloning with different branch other than master

`git clone --branch dummybranch --single-branch repolink`

Is there any way to contain both branch at single local repo with different commits?

Comment: `git checkout -b ...` does exactly what had been asked for, i.e. it creates a new branch which points directly to the same HEAD as your current one, presumable *master*. That's why you see master's commits there. You need to checkout differently, e.g. `git checkout -b dummy origin/dummy`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+push+multiple+remotes

Answer (score 6):

`git clone` has already cloned every branch to your repository. But it hasn't created local branches for all of them, just `master`. The rest are in remote tracking branches which are prefixed with the name of the remote, `origin`. You can see them with `git branch -r`.

The remote's master branch is in the remote tracking branch `origin/master`. Their `dummy` is in `origin/dummy`. Your repo looks something like this.

```
              [origin/master]
A - B - C - D [master]
     \
      E - F [origin/dummy]
```

Cloning has created a local `master` branch, but no local `dummy`.

By default, when you make a new branch it is off of the current branch. If you had `master` checked out, which you would right after cloning, then `git checkout -b dummy` make a branch called `dummy` off of `master`.

```
$ git checkout -b dummy

              [dummy]
              [origin/master]
A - B - C - D [master]
     \
      E - F [origin/dummy]
```

That's not right. We want it off `origin/dummy`.

After deleting the incorrect dummy, `git branch -d dummy`, we can checkout origin/dummy and then make the branch.

```
git checkout origin/dummy
git checkout -b dummy

              [origin/master]
A - B - C - D [master]
     \
      E - F [origin/dummy]
            [dummy]
```

Or as a shorthand, we can pass in where we want to branch from

```
git checkout -b dummy origin/dummy
```

Or, even shorter, you can simply checkout your non-existent `dummy` branch and Git will assume it's supposed to be the local branch of `origin/dummy`. This is controlled by the `--guess` option, on by default.

```
git checkout dummy
Branch 'dummy' set up to track remote branch 'dummy' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'dummy'
```

See [Working With Remotes in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) for more.

Comment: Not sure if its old or what, but when I check out a branch that has the same name as a remote branch, it automatically links it to the "origin" branch.